# Angular: pass a default value from server side

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have on the server side (.NET Razor) a texbox that specified a default radius for a google map zoom that user can modify:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="radius">
```

But also for the first load, I should have a server-defined(and managed) variable

```
<input type="number" ng-model="defaultRadius" 
       style="display: none;" value="@myDefault">
```

Here is the code ([JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19432/))

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Superhero';
  $scope.$watch('defaultRadius', function(newValue) {
    $scope.radius = newValue;
  }, true);
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">Hello, {{name}}!
  <h2>Enter your radius (default {{defaultRadius}}): </h2>
  <input type="number" ng-model="radius">
  <input type="number" ng-model="defaultRadius" 
         style="display: none;" value="200">
</div>
```

However this does not seem to work... How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Angular way you should define the model in the controller, not in the view.
so you need to create a variable in your controller

```
 $scope.defaultRadius = 200';
```

or there is another trick to do this use : `ng-init="defaultRadius=200"`

```
<input type="number" ng-model="defaultRadius" style="display: none;" ng-init="defaultRadius=200"  >
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19435/)**

Comment: I can't pass a value from the server to a javascript file

Comment: than you can use ng-init="defaultRadius=200" this will work

Comment: that was a good idea! could you complete with this remark your answer that I could mark it as answer? ;) because your comment is the answer, not the answer itself ;)

Comment: I'd note, however, that there is no "another trick", there is *the only way* to pass the value *from the server*

Comment: it's a trick because it's not the best way, best way is the controller , in case of  value from the server, we need to put a ajax call on server to get default value and update it in controller and than view automatically show that